# Spark graphX make Edge/Vertex RDD from dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, type-conversion, spark-graphx

I have 2 large dataframes, `edge` and `vertex`, and I know that they need to be in special type `Vertex` and `Edge` RDDs, but every tutorial that I have found specifies the `Edge` and `Vertex` RDDs as  arrays of 3 to 10 items. I need them to directly convert from a substantial RDD. How would I change a dataframe/normal RDD into the correct type?

I have followed the example here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#example-property-graph but it enumerates all relationships and there are many in my use case.

- `edge` df has 3 columns, (sourceID, destID, relationship)
- `vertex` df has 2 columns (ID, Name)

What I have tried so far:

```
val vertex: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = sc.parallelize((vertexDF("ID"), vertexDF("Name")))
```

Returns Error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : (org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
 required: Seq[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, String)]
    (which expands to)  Seq[(Long, String)]
```

How would I change a dataframe/normal RDD into the specialized vertex/edge RDD types?

Answer (score 2):

There is a graphframes spark library to handle dataframe-based graphs.
It has a method to convert an edge and vertices dataframe pair into a GraphX RDD. See:
http://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/user-guide.html#example-conversions.

For your example it will looks like:

```
val edgeDf = .... // (sourceID, destID, relationship)
val verexDf = .... // (ID, Name)
import org.graphframes._
val g = GraphFrame(
  verexDf.select($"id", $"name"), 
  edgeDf.select ($"sourceID" as "src", $"destID" as "dst", $"relationship"))
// Convert to GraphX
val gx: Graph[Row, Row] = g.toGraphX
```